# Alternative registration / authentication for Django that doesn't involve reinventing the wheel

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration

I'm using `django 1.8` and `django-registration-redux` to build a registration/login workflow. Right now, I'm using the default backend that prevents the user from logging in unless they go to their email and click the activation email. This introduces an obvious point of friction in the registration flow.

Basically - I want users to be able to register and start using my site, right after they register, without having to go back to their email and click the activation link.

But, I still want the activation email to be sent - I just don't want users blocked on it per se. My current plan is to write a sweeper that alerts me to unactivated users after some period of time, or just go through the DB manually and see who is unactivated, and take some future action manually.

Another way of looking at it - basically, I want a distinction between `email_is_valid` and `user_is_active` - right now the `is_active` flag sort of conflates the two of them. It's also more complicated than I would like because is_active seems to be used in a lot of places by default to allow login or not (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active )

Is there a clean way of doing this with django-registration-redux? I'd rather not write my own backend (and the associated tests, technical/management debt, etc) - alternatively if there's a preexisting alternative django-registration-redux backend out there that provides this, I'll happily use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do email validation, rather than using the email for activation. It appears that django-registration-redux does not support that type of flow. It provides (via the default backend) the flow you are seeing, where a user is put into an activation queue until they click the link in their email, or (via the simple backend), the user is directly signed up and no email is sent out.

From my understanding, email validation in this manner is outside the scope of django-registration-redux. However, you may be able to find the functionality you're looking for in django-allauth. That package includes out-of-band email validation, as well as support for multiple email addresses per account, all validated separately.